# systemctl service hang on start command, no logs in journalctl

Tags: linux, service, raspbian, systemd, systemctl

I am trying to understand why my service isn't starting on some of my devices but is starting on others. When I try to do systemctl start pishock.service it just hangs, it doesn't give me any output, it doesn't start the service, it just hangs there. It's an head scratcher because it works on others very close environment. (Same raspbian, same versions of systemctl and same version of python)

```
[Unit]
Description=PiShock Client
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/PiShockClient.pyc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I try to start PiShockClient.pyc normally by entering `sudo python3 PiShockClient.pyc` it starts sucessfully.
The code above works on some of my other Pi Zero Ws
I have done apt-get upgrade, apt-get dist-upgrade.

The weird part is that there's no logs in journalctl, even under `journalctl -xe`. It just hangs like it never tries to start the service.

I am at a complete loss.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.